# tips for removing stuck heatsink

Tags: cpu, heatsink

am having real issues today (possibly due to the previous days festivities).  Basically I am trying to remove the stock intel heatsink from a core i3 processor (socket 1156) and the bugget wont come off.  I have twisted the fasteners the requisite 90 degrees but two of them will not disengage from the motherboard.

does anyone have any suggestions about how best to remove it while protecting the motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice I can give is make sure the fasteners are full twisted and give each one a tug to try and disengage them.  You can also try using a precision screwdriver to push the plastic pin up from the bottom.  Once that's done, it should be a fairly straight forward affair for removing it.

Comment: screwdriver from the bottom, sounds dangerous but might just do the trick!  thanks

Comment: If you support the heatsink (which should be the tallest item on your motherboard) then you should be fine.  there shouldn't be any lines within about an eighth of an inch of the pin, so you do have some room to slip off.

Comment: now that was an excellent suggestion.  worked like a charm.